# Accessing MariaDB with R Shiny App (on same server)

Tags: r, shiny, mariadb, database-connection

I have a server in a local network on which both a MariaDB and R Shiny are installed. For testing purposes I have created a database with a table and a very simple R Shiny app, which should display this table. If the Shiny App runs on my computer, it can access the database on the server and display the table without any problems. But when I deploy the app on the server (host changed to 127.0.0.1) the title of the app is displayed briefly, but the app disconnects immediately when trying to display the table. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be? I thank you in advance for any hints.

Here my server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)    
library(RMariaDB) 
library(pool) 
library(DT)

pool <- dbPool(
    drv      = MariaDB(),
    user     = "user",
    password = "user-password",
    host     = "127.0.0.1",
    port     = 3306,
    dbname   = "test")

onStop(function() {
    poolClose(pool)
})

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({        
        dbReadTable(pool, "table1")
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I unfortunately overlooked the fact that RMariaDB was not correctly installed on the R Server. The installation failed because no mysql client library was found on the server. By installing libmariadbclient-dev on the server and reinstalling the RMariaDB R-package, everything works fine now.